# CSS Menu List double Nesting

Tags: html, css

I want a menu with a mouseover show property Inside it I want to use a second unordered list to show the second hidin menu. The problem is that my first rule overwrites the second menus properties and all list items show .
This is my menu html.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="./index.html">ANASAYFA</a></li>
    <li><a href="./blog-1.html">HAKKIMIZDA</a></li>
    <li><a href="./portfolio-3c.html">HİZMETLERİMİZ</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./portfolio-3c.html">Eğitim Hizmetlerimiz</a>
                <ul class="menu2">
                    <li  class="current"><a href="./blog-1.html">Ygs-Lys hazırlık programları</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./blog-2.html">Sbs'ye Hazırlık programı'</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./blog-1.html">Ana sınıg 1'e 1 test programı</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./blog-2.html">Okul destek programı</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="./portfolio-2c.html">Neurofeedback</a></li>
            <li><a href="./portfolio-2c.html">Bioofeedback</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="./gallery.html">GALERİ</a></li><li><a href="#">STYLINGS</a>
   <li><a href="./stylings-texts.html">SANAL TUR</a></li>
   <li><a href="./stylings-table_columns.html">BİZE ULAŞIN</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">İletişim Formu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">İletişim Bilgileri</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my css file for menu orginal and menu2 nested ul

```
#sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 {margin: 0px auto;width: 100%;z-index: 30;float: left;}
 #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 li {line-height: 32px;text-align: center;width: 100%;background-image: url('../images/menu_li.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: bottom center;clear: left;float: left;color: #999999;}
 #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 li a, #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 .current ul li a {font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;display: block;color: #999999;}
 #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 li:hover{background-image: url('../images/menu_li_hover.png');}
 #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 li a:hover, #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2  .current a, #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 li ul li a:hover{color: #ffffff; }
 #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 li ul{display: none;}#sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 li ul li{background-image: url('../images/menu_subli.png');}
 #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu2 li ul li a{font-size: 11px;}
```

Can you show me a way to make it work?

Comment: Instead of using your code try the following code http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/popupmenu.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent your first rule to override properties using

```
menu > li { /* css properties */ }
```

which will just affect the immediate `li's`

Or you can also use something like this -

```
#menu2 ul li { /* write the css again so the override does not happen */ }
```